# How do I use "get records" to get the account owner of an asset?

Tags: recordtriggeredflow, task-notifications

I am creating a flow to send a task to the account owner if the asset's status hasn't been changed to "live" after 30 days. I cannot figure out how to use the "Get records" element to get this information. I am also wondering if I even put it in the right spot? Any help is appreciated! I am new to flows, so I'm curious if I set this up correctly.

[image: screenshot of my flow]

Comment: Assuming this Flow runs on Asset, then `$Record.Account.OwnerId` should have the value of the asset's Account's ownerId.

Comment: I can't get it to work. When I debug it, it says "This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: MALFORMED_ID: Assigned To ID: id value of incorrect type: $Record.Account.OwnerId."

Comment: Use [edit] and show your revised flow, debug panel, and assignment statement